# python typing Dict and overloading: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments

Tags: python, overloading, python-typing

```py
@overload
def get_random(
        d:Dict[int,int]
)->int:
    ...

@overload
def get_random(
        d:Dict[int,float]
)->float:
    ...

def get_random(
        d: Dict[int,Union[int,float]]
)->Union[int,float]:
    key = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
    return d[key]


a: int = get_random({1:1})
b: float = get_random({1:1.})
```

mypy provides the following message:

> > error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 1

I am afraid I do not understand what the issue is.

(note: I am aware that an alternative working solution is to use TypeVar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Dict[int, Union[int, float]]` is not the same as `Union[Dict[int, int], Dict[int, float]]` which is what you meant.

```
import random
from typing import Dict, Union, overload


@overload
def get_random(d: Dict[int, int]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def get_random(d: Dict[int, float]) -> float:
    ...


def get_random(d: Union[Dict[int, int], Dict[int, float]]) -> Union[int, float]:
    key = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
    return d[key]


reveal_type(get_random({1: 1.0}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
reveal_type(get_random({1: 1}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```

**mypy** still gives an error here due to its strict policy about overlapping overloaded variants. Note that `int` is a subtype of `float`, therefore, for example, `{1: 2}` will match both variants.
Read more [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-the-variants).

If the order of variants is swapped, the discrepancy is clear, as the revealed type is `float` in both cases.

```py
import random
from typing import Dict, Union, overload


@overload
def get_random(d: Dict[int, float]) -> float:
    ...


@overload
def get_random(d: Dict[int, int]) -> int:
    ...


def get_random(d: Union[Dict[int, int], Dict[int, float]]) -> Union[int, float]:
    key = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
    return d[key]


reveal_type(get_random({1: 1.0}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
reveal_type(get_random({1: 1}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
```

Consider using a `TypeVar` instead.

```py
import random
from typing import Dict, TypeVar

Number = TypeVar("Number", int, float)


def get_random(d: Dict[int, Number]) -> Number:
    key = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
    return d[key]


reveal_type(get_random({1: 1.0}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
reveal_type(get_random({1: 1}))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```